# Python reverse converts? (fraction)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

Coded in Python 3.6.4 for the system to basically print "4/1", "4/3", "4/5", "4/7" and so on. The result was correct in that it did print those values but it made them seemingly the biggest number possible except for the first one.

```
4
6004799503160661/4503599627370496
3602879701896397/4503599627370496
2573485501354569/4503599627370496
2001599834386887/4503599627370496
```

The code I put in went like this

```
from fractions import Fraction
q = int(input("Choose a number: "))
a = 4
count = q
w = 1
while count > 0:
    print(str(Fraction(a/w)))
    count = count - 1
    w = w + 2
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: `Fraction(a/w)` creates a fraction from the floating point approximation... Why not `Fraction(a, w)`? I'd recommend reading [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be doing: `print(str(Fraction(a, w)))`, not `print(str(Fraction(a/w)))`. What's happening here is you are getting the value of `a/w` and then trying to make it a Fraction, which results in the strange numbers you're getting.

Compare:

```
>>> Fraction(2/3)
Fraction(6004799503160661, 9007199254740992)
>>> Fraction(2, 3)
Fraction(2, 3)
```